# Calling static delegate with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I need to call a delegate method using reflection, passing the name of the method as a string.

For example, I'll pass `My.Controls.TestDelegate.myConverterAction` where `TestDelegate` is the class name and `myConverterAction` is the delegate:

```
namespace My.Controls
{
    public static class TestDelegate
    {
        public static CustomConversionHandler myConverterAction = new CustomConversionHandler(doSomething);

        private static ulong doSomething(object[] values)
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought to use the `GetMethod()` method in this way:

```
int separator = actionDelegate.LastIndexOf('.');
string className = actionDelegate.Substring(0, separator);
string methodName = actionDelegate.Substring(separator + 1, actionDelegate.Length - className.Length - 1);

var t = Type.GetType(className); //This works
MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static); //This returns null...even with different BindingFlags options
```

but I obtain a null reference.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It would also help if you provided valid sample code - your first piece of code appears to use `using` as if it's a `namespace` declaration... a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I need to call a delegate that is of CustomConversionHandler type. I need to do this for several classes and the only thing I know about this classes is that they are declared static and have a static delegate property of CustomConversionHandler type. I only can get the "full" name in the form of "namespace.className.delegateProperty"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `TestDelegate.myConverterAction` is a static **field** and not a **method** you should retrieve it using the following code:

```
FieldInfo info = typeof(TestDelegate).GetField("myConverterAction", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
object yourField = info.GetValue(null);
```

Than in order to invoke it you need to get it's invoke method using:

```
MethodInfo method = yourField.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke");
```

And invoke the `Invoke` method using `MethodInfo.Invoke()`:

```
method.Invoke(yourField, new {new object[]{"123"}});
```

Comment: Simple and clear. Thank you for your brilliant reply.

Comment: @rPulvi Maybe for the last part you can simply use `var result = ((CustomConversionHandler)yourField)(new object[] { "123", });`. But why do you need reflection in the first place?

Comment: I assumed he does not know the `Type` of the `Delegate` from where he uses reflection. If he does so yeah, it is possible.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I have to use reflection because I don't know neither the name of the class nor the field name that represents the delegate

Answer (score 0):

Your `myConverterAction` is a field, not a method. You can either change it to be a method:

```
public static void MyConverterAction(object arg) 
{

}
```

Or use a method `Type.GetField()` instead.

And the other thing: when you use `BindingFlags.Instance` you cannot capture a static field, nor a method. It restricts only to instance (non static) members. Use `BindingFlags.Static` instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right. With GetField I'm able to get the right FieldInfo. But now, how can I call the method linked to this delegate?

PS: I know about the BindingFlags. As mentioned in the post, I tried several combinations. Anyway, I'll edit the question to avoid misunderstanding, thank you.